mui data grid with nextjs column definition error
I'm using mui data grid in a next.js app I'm building. The problem is when I try to do a more complex column definition I run into an error:
{
    field: 'home_address',
    valueGetter: (value, row) => {
        return (row.user.home_address);
    },
    headerName: 'Address' 
},

The error reads: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server". {field: ..., valueGetter: function, headerName: ...}
I can hide this error by passing in use server to the closure like this:
{
    field: 'home_address',
    valueGetter: async (value, row) => {
        'use server'
        return (row.user.home_address);
    },
    headerName: 'Address' 
},

but then my address column renders:
[object Promise]
Is there a workaround for this, or a way to force the async closure to resolve before returning?

Remove async from
valueGetter: async (value, row) => {....} So you dont get Promise [object Promise] as return value

@Menoly nextjs says Server actions must be async functions if you remove that.

The problem here is that NextJs uses server components as default. It means that the components are rendered in the server side, instead of client side. Because of this, you can't use state inside a server component. That's why you cannot render a datagrid column dynamically as you're trying to do here:
{
    field: 'home_address',
    valueGetter: (value, row) => {
        return (row.user.home_address);
    },
    headerName: 'Address' 
},

To be able to do that, you have to alert NextJs that this component must rendered in the client side. To do that you just have to add "use client" in the top of the component like this:
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { DataGrid, GridColDef } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const columns: GridColDef<(typeof rows)[number]>[] = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    type: "number",
    width: 110,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "fullName",
    headerName: "Full name",
    description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
    sortable: false,
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (value, row) => `${row.firstName || ""} ${row.lastName || ""}`,
  },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", age: 14 },
  { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Cersei", age: 31 },
  { id: 3, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Jaime", age: 31 },
  { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 11 },
  { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: null },
  { id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: "Clifford", firstName: "Ferrara", age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: "Frances", firstName: "Rossini", age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: "Roxie", firstName: "Harvey", age: 65 },
];

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: {
              pageSize: 5,
            },
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Test;

You can learn more about this in the NextJs docs:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components
